# What happened to the .Net Framework Configuration tool?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-3.5

Older versions of the .Net Framework used to install "Microsoft .NET Framework v1.0 / v1.1 / v2.0 Configuration" in the Control Panel, under Administrative Tools. I just noticed that there isn't a v3.0 or v3.5 version of this. Is this functionality now hiding somewhere else, or do I have to use the command-line tools instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework versions 3.0 and 3.5 have been built incrementally on the .NET Framework version 2.0. This version can be used to manage code access security policy for the .NET Framework 3.0, 3.5, and later versions as well.

Answer (score 3):

For 3.5, you must install this tool:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377f86d-c913-4b5c-b87e-ef72e5b4e065&displaylang=en

And for 3.0 you must use the 2.0 config tool.

[Source of Answer](http://forums.msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/9aa72b12-3b63-493b-a7d2-596775bd66ea/).

Answer (score 2):

Both 3 and 3.5 still use the [Common Language Runtime of .NET Framework 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_.NET#.NET_Framework_3.0). So no control panel is needed, as you can still use the 2.0 control panel.

Answer (score 1):

To sort out the confusion between the apparently conflicting answers above, this is my current understanding of the answer:

- Use the 2.0 version, as DAC and Codeslayer recommended
- If you don't *have* the 2.0 version (mine was helpfully uninstalled when I removed VS2005 and installed VS2008), then you can either install VS2005, or download the Windows SDK, as per GateKiller's link

On my PC, even downloading the SDK didn't work; it installed mscorcfg.msc but not mscorcfg.dll. Digging about in the GAC, I notice mscorcfg.dll v3.5, which confuses me even more. Anyway, there is an iffy-looking copy-dlls-and-hack-registry solution at http://home.hot.rr.com/graye/Articles/CodeAccessSecurity.htm, and that's what I'm going to try next. Wish me luck!